# How to Programme 3rd Party nrf52832 (DollaTek NRF52832 Bluetooth Module BLE )

Tags: embedded, bluetooth-lowenergy, nrf52

I am coming from programming Arduino and want to use NRF52832 - I have found [this](https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B07HBWKTKP?psc=1&ref=ppx_yo2ov_dt_b_product_details) board which a 3rd party breakout board for NRF52832 - I want to use this so that I can use a similar design for the antenna.

Question - I have an [ST-LINK](https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B07YX83NSL?psc=1&ref=ppx_yo2ov_dt_b_product_details) programmer but I am reading that I need a J-LINK can somebody pls help me understand if I can use the ST-LINK or I need J-LINK or if I need to order a nordic development board (for licensing purposes) before I can program? Also any references to set up the connection would be really helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I use a nrf52dk as programmer for 3rd party boards/nrf52 modules. ST-link v2 will work but haven't tried it yet.

https://devzone.nordicsemi.com/f/nordic-q-a/21415/flashing-nrf52832-chip-with-st-link-v2

For nordic ble device I recommend searching and asking in their forum. Engineers are very helpful and forum is full of different topics from users.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I will post a proper answer after I have tested but for now this looks like the [solution](https://youtu.be/WuWkLqHqn9Q):

1. Connect STLINK GND, 3.3V,SWDIO,SWCLK
2. Download Sandeep Mistrys NRF [library](https://github.com/sandeepmistry/arduino-nRF5)

3. Programme via Arduino GUI